# Can not set variables of service in a controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

In angular i have authentication service which made call to the server.

```
pp.factory('authService', ['api','$cookieStore', function(api, $cookieStore, ACCESS_LEVELS){

     var AuthentoctionControllerUrl = "http://localhost:18678/api/Authentication/";  
     var isAuth;
     var IsAdmin;
     function Login(credential){
        return api.Post(AuthentoctionControllerUrl + "ByPassword" ,null , credential);
     };

    var Logout = function() {
         $cookieStore.remove('AuthorizationHeader');
         isAuth = false;
     };

     var AccessPrivilegesAdmin = function(user_type){
         if(IsAdmin == user_type) return true;
         return false;
     };

     var AccessPrivilegesAuth = function(){
         return isAuth;
     };

    return {
        Login  : Login,
        Logout : Logout,
        isAuth : isAuth,
        IsAdmin : IsAdmin,
        AccessPrivilegesAuth : AccessPrivilegesAuth,
        AccessPrivilegesAdmin : AccessPrivilegesAdmin
     };
 }]);
```

the service have two variables which are isAuth and is Admin which currently they are undfiend.However when i call that controller should set them to a value and i can see it in the debug mode.

```
app.controller('LoginController', ['$scope', '$location', 'authService','$cookieStore', function($scope, $location, authService, $cookieStore){
     $scope.loginData = {
         EmailAddress : "",
         password : ""
     };

     $scope.error; $scope.error_exist = false; 
     $scope.login = function(){
         authService.Login($scope.loginData).success(function(response){
             $cookieStore.put('AuthorizationHeader', response.Token);
             authService.isAuth = true;
             authService.IsAdmin = response.IsAdmin;
             $location.path('categories');
         }).error(function(Error){
             $scope.error_exist = true;
             switch(Error.ExceptionMessage){
                case "201" :
                     $scope.error = "The emailAddress/password pair don't match an existing member"; break;
                case "210" :
                     $scope.error = "Value cannot be null missing Email Address and/or password."; break;
                case "202" :
                     $scope.error = "The email address you are using isn't confirmed. Please see your inbox for further instructions."; break;
                default : 
                     $scope.error = "Error with the server";
             }
         });

     };
 }]);
```

the problem is i have event on rout change that calls that method AccessPrivilegesAuth that should return isAuth which i have set in the controller however when i call that method the return of isAuth is undfiend i am sure that i had set its value in the controller as `authService.isAuth = true;`
Edit just worked find by adding this keyword to isAuth and isAdmin in the factory.
new code.

```
var AccessPrivilegesAdmin = function(user_type){
     if(this.IsAdmin == user_type) return true;
     return false;
 };

 var AccessPrivilegesAuth = function(){
     return this.isAuth;
 };
```

i don't understand why it works with this any explanation ?

Answer (score 0):

The issue seems to be that the call to the server is not complete when you are accessing AccessPrivilegesAuth so that is why it returns undefined.

You can solve this issue by putting the Login code inside the resolve function of the route you are using.

Here is some sample code from this blog post http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2014/05/20/using-resolve-in-angularjs-routes.aspx:

```
$routeProvider
    .when("/news", {
        templateUrl: "newsView.html",
        controller: "newsController",
        resolve: {
            message: function(messageService){
                return messageService.getMessage();
        }
    }
})
```

As you can see in the resolve function, there is a call to the server and the result, the object 'message', can be injected directly into the controller like this:

```
app.controller('LoginController', ['$scope', 'message', 
  function($scope, message) {
```

And message can be used within the controller

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your help but when i modified that part of the code 
var AccessPrivilegesAuth = function(){
         return this.isAuth;
     };
it worked fine i do not understand why but it worked.

Comment: only add this keyword